# Highlight day of event PHP calendar

Tags: php, calendar, highlight

I have made an PHP Event calender where the user can add events..

Now i want to highlight the day where there is an event. I have already highlighted the current day like shown on te sreenshot:

http://i41.tinypic.com/t0nlti.png

```
</script>
<style>
.today{
background-color: #00ff00;
}
.event{
background-color: #FF8080;
}
</style>
```

Actual code:

```
$monthstring = $month;
$monthlength = strlen($monthstring);
$daystring = $i;
$daylength = strlen($daystring);
if($monthlength <= 1){
$monthstring = "0".$monthstring;
}
if($daylength <=1){
$daystring = "0".$daystring;
}
$todaysDate = date("m/d/Y");
$dateToCompare = $monthstring. '/' . $daystring. '/' . $year;
echo "<td align='center' ";
if ($todaysDate == $dateToCompare){
echo "class ='today'";
} 
//here it goes wrong..
else
{
 $sqlCount = "select * from eventcalendar where eventDate='".$dateToCompare."'";
 $noOfEvent = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($sqlCount));
 if($noOfEvent >= 1){
 echo "class='event'";
 }
}
```

As you see the highlighting of today goes fine.

```
$eventsdate = $month."-".$month."-".$day;
```

DB layout:

http://i41.tinypic.com/2luvok4.png

Hope anyone can help me.

Comment: Please, please, pleeeease, get away from the standard MysQL-functions and use something like MySQLi or PDO.

Can you do a var_dump() of $dateToCompare? what does it say?

Comment: Oh and I'm not sure (I never am) about case sensitivity on table fields. In your PHP Script you do a WHERE on "eventDate" and on the screenshot it says "EventDate"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$dateToCompare` is in the m/d/y format wheareas your db dates are stored in the y-m-d format.

For simplicity (and assuming these variables aren't used anywhere else) you can keep everything in the same format:

```
$todaysDate = date("Y-m-d");
$dateToCompare = $year . '-'.$monthstring. '-' . $daystring;
```

Comment: Thank you! Can't believe I missed that, maybe because of all those hours of coding without coffee! hahah thanks again.